# export datagridview according to displayed colums

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a datagridview with `column reordering = True`. I have changed the orders of the columns  and want to extract according to this reordered data.
Here is datagridview with default values.[image]

Now i have reordered the columns as :

[image]

i want to export the data to a text file according to this reordered columns.

When i am using the code :

```
        Dim Strng As String = Nothing ' dgg is datagridview '
        For i As Integer = 0 To dgg.RowCount - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To dgg.Columns.Count - 1
                Strng += vbNewLine + dgg.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value
            Next
        Next
```

it showing acc as column 0 and newacc as column 2. But i need data as it is in dridview i.e. name in column 0 and add in column 1..

Please help me out . Thanks in advance..

Comment: put some code here! what you want to extract, to where I think you confuse the view from datagridview and data from db .. be more specific what you want !

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the primitiveness of this example, and I make assumptions about how you want to export (through CSV is a common format). No matter what you do, the key is to export the data for an individual row in the order of that row's column's DisplayIndex property.

```
        //put columns in order of display
        List<DataGridViewColumn> columnsInOrder = new List<DataGridViewColumn>();

        foreach(DataGridViewColumn c in this.dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            columnsInOrder.Add(c);
        }

        columnsInOrder = columnsInOrder.OrderBy(c => c.DisplayIndex).ToList();

        //read rows into lines of strings that can be exported as a CSV file
        List<string> CSVExportLines = new List<string>();

        foreach(DataGridViewRow r in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            List<string> valuesInOrder = new List<string>();

            //go through columns by order of display index, pull values by the "real" index
            foreach(DataGridViewColumn c in columnsInOrder)
            {
                valuesInOrder.Add(r.Cells[c.Index].ToString());
            }

            CSVExportLines.Add(string.Join(",", valuesInOrder.ToArray())); //add one CSV line (join all individual values into a string with commas in between)
        }

        File.WriteAllLines("C:\somepath\somefile.csv", CSVExportLines.ToArray());
```